# Launch an HTML page as a self-contained desktop app

Tags: html, desktop-application, launch

How can I distribute a program that is only an HTML page (and its resources), so that it will launch in its own window as a self-contained desktop application?

Some programs are released as a bundle of files with the instruction “use your web browser to open this HTML file”. An example is [MuscleBook](https://github.com/cfilipov/MuscleBook.net). The program runs entirely locally, using resources bundled in the download, and the web browser is merely a UI and execution platform.

What I want is an easy way to install a command-line wrapper that will launch that web page from local storage, in a window that presents the program and allows the user to interact with it like any other desktop application. It should not require the user to open a web browser program, and should not appear in a tab of some existing open browser program.

The Mozilla project made [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XULRunner) which seems to be what I'm looking for. But that project is now “archived” and no longer supported. What should I use instead, to deploy an existing HTML app as a desktop app?

Answer (score 2):

This might be reasonably relevant:

https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier